# Como utilizar order by parar ordernar os nomes dos mes em Oracle

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, query, oracle

Olá, gostaria de saber como resolver esse problema. Gostaria de pegar o nome dos dias do mês e ordena-los e não os números dos meses correspondentes.
Segue a consulta que realizei mas que ordena somente em números correspondentes aos meses.

```
SELECT to_char(hsp_checkin, 'month') as "Mês", 
       count(hsp_id) as "Total de Hospedagens" 
FROM HOSPEDAGENS
GROUP BY to_char(hsp_checkin, 'month');
```

---

Pequena correção na descrição da pergunta. "Gostaria de pegar o nome dos dias do mês" na verdade é: Gostaria de pegar o nome dos meses.

Comment: ORDER BY 1 não resolve?

Comment: No caso você quer ordenar pela contagem "Total de Hospedagens"?

Comment: Order by 1 não resolve. Eu quero ordenar pelo nome dos meses e não pelos números que os representam. Ex: Janeiro, Fevereiro, Março, e não, Abril, Agosto...

Answer (score 1):

Como comentado na pergunta, você deve adicionar a cláusula `order by`:

```
SELECT to_char(hsp_checkin, 'month') as "Mês", 
   count(hsp_id) as "Total de Hospedagens" 
FROM HOSPEDAGENS
GROUP BY to_char(hsp_checkin, 'month')
ORDER BY 1; -- to_char(hsp_checkin, 'month')
```

Comment: Ainda não está ordenando pelos nomes dos meses.

Comment: seria ordem alfabética?

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT   to_char(hsp_checkin, 'month') as "Mês", 
         count(hsp_id) as "Total de Hospedagens",
         extract(year from hsp_checkin) as ano, 
         extract(month from hsp_checkin) as mes
FROM HOSPEDAGENS
GROUP BY to_char(hsp_checkin, 'month'),
         extract(year from hsp_checkin), 
         extract(month from hsp_checkin)
ORDER BY ano, mes;
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).